# Python / MySQL error at insertion

Tags: python, mysql

Hi guys I am trying to insert some values into MySQL database after crawling them using python from website.But it gives me error while inserting them into database .
Error is as follows: mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 2
.

please help me. Thanks in advance. Below is the code:

```
conn =     mysql.connector.connect(user='root',password='root',host='localhost',database ='crawler_database')
mycursor = conn.cursor()
source_code = requests.get(item_url)
plain_text = source_code.text
soup = BeautifulSoup(plain_text)
my_list=[]
# GATHER INFORMATION FROM PAGE
for product_name in soup.findAll('span', {'itemprop': 'name'}):
    prod_name = " " + product_name.string
    my_list.append(prod_name)
    print("Product Name :" + prod_name)
for low_price in soup.findAll('span', {'itemprop': 'lowPrice'}):
    l_price = " " + low_price.string
    my_list.append(l_price)
    print("Lowest price :" + low_price.string)
for high_price in soup.findAll('span', {'itemprop': 'highPrice'}):
    h_price = " " + high_price.string
    my_list.append(h_price)
    print("Highest price :" + high_price.string)
# FORMAT AND REMOVE UNWANTED CHARACTER FROM DATA
for specs in soup.findAll('ul', {'class': 'c-spec'}):
    crop_str1 = str(specs).replace("<li>", "")
    crop_str2 = crop_str1.replace("</li>", ",")
    crop_str3 = crop_str2.replace("</ul>", "%")
    crop_str4 = crop_str3.replace('<ul class="c-spec">', '$')
    crop_str5 = crop_str4.partition('$')[-1].rpartition('%')[0]
    my_list2 = crop_str5.split(",")
    merged_list=my_list+my_list2
    print(merged_list)
    d0=" " + str(merged_list[0])
    d1=" " + str(merged_list[1])
    d2=" " + str(merged_list[2])
    d3=" " + str(merged_list[3])
    d4=" " + str(merged_list[4])
    d5=" " + str(merged_list[5])
    d6=" " + str(merged_list[6])
    print("Android OS :" + merged_list[3])
    print("Camera :" + merged_list[4])
    print("SIM :" + merged_list[5])
    print("Display size :" + merged_list[6])
    mycursor.execute("""INSERT INTO mobile_spec(prod_name, low_price, high_price, android_os, camera, sim, d_size)
             VALUES ((%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s , %s)""",(d0, d1, d2, d3, d4, d5, d6))
    conn.commit()
```

Comment: assuming fields `android_os, camera, sim, d_size` are varchar, you have to string literal quote them in values clause like : `VALUES ('d0','d1','d2','d3')`. although you probably want to use the values in variables $d0 ( so concatenate ( with the string literal characters )

Comment: but it is inserting d0, d1, d2, d3 in table instead of inserting values which I retrieve from my_list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're passing the actual strings "d0", etc, to MySQL, which has no idea what to do with them. Those are Python variables, so you need to pass their values to MySQL instead. You do that with placeholders:

```
mycursor.execute("""INSERT INTO mobile_spec(android_os, camera, sim, d_size)
                 VALUES (%s, %s, %s , %s)""", (d0, d1, d2, d3))
```

Your code can be simplified further, since you get the params in a list in the first place, so you can pass that directly to MySQL without the `d*` variables at all.

```
mycursor.execute("""INSERT INTO mobile_spec(android_os, camera, sim, d_size)
                 VALUES (%s, %s, %s , %s)""", my_list)
```

Comment: heyy daniel thanks,But when I added more parameters to it it gaves another syntax error.I checked the code but didnt found any syntax error.Please help me friend.

Comment: If you've made a change and are getting an error, you should post the change you've made and that error.

Comment: ya change is in the code.Now I have made list of 7 elements.that is the only change I had made.

Comment: You still didn't post the error. But I see that you have two opening parentheses in the SQL query.